# What's an efficient geometry rendering strategy?

Tags: performance, opengl, graphics, rendering

Describe an efficient strategy for rendering the geometry from the point of 
view of the OpenGL code that you would use (exact commands are not 
required).

I assume it mostly consists of grouping similar geometry whether it be models that share the same the meshes and/or the materials into particular VBOs?

Comment: What is your target app trying to do?

Comment: Just render a model's geometry with materials and textures.

Comment: how many models and what platform?

Comment: It's an abstract question designed to be applicable to the majority of situations.

Comment: But there's a huge divide between mobile opengl and modern opengl on desktop.

Comment: Let's say modern opengl on desktop then 3.2 to be exact.

Comment: Vertex pointers are cheap to change (relative to everything else you mentioned). You do not necessarily need to bundle everything into a massive VBO that can be drawn in a single call, but you ***do*** want to minimize render target (FBO), shader and texture state changes between each draw call. Changing those states will make a draw call *significantly* more expensive.

Comment: This question is far too broad for Stack Overflow. You might ask it over on the Programmer Stack Exchange.